# Live variable analysis , is my explanation correct?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, register-allocation, dataflow-diagram

As [stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) have not more tags about compiler tags , so I'm posting here , this question .

---

A variable x is said to be live at a statement Si in a program if the following three conditions hold simultaneously :

```
1. There exists a statement Sj that uses x
2. There is a path from Si to Sj in the flow
   graph corresponding to the program
3. The path has no intervening assignment to x 
   including at Si and Sj
```

[image]

The variables which are live both at the statement in basic block 2 and at the statement in basic block 3 of the above control flow graph are

1. p, s, u
2. r, s, u
3. r, u
4. q, v

---

I try to explain :

---

As the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis) says "Stated simply: a variable is live if it holds a value that may be needed in the future."

As per the definition given in question, a variable is live if it is used in future before any new assignment.
Block 2 has ‘r’ and ‘v’ both as live variables. as they are used in block 4 before any new value assinged to them. Note that variable ‘u’ is not live in block 2 as ‘u’ is assigned a new value in block 1 before it is used in block 3. Variables ‘p’, ‘s’ and ‘q’ are also not live in block 2 due to same reason.
Block 3 has only ‘r’ as live variable as every other variable is assigned a new value before use.

---

Another explanation given as :

---

Only r.

p, s and u are assigned to in 1 and there is no intermediate use of them before that. Hence p, s and u are not live in both 2 and 3.
q is assigned to in 4 and hence is not live in both 2 and 3.

v is live at 3 but not at 2.
Only r is live at both 2 and 3.

But official GATE key said both r and u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things that are probably at least part of your confusion.

First, in the list of conditions for live variables, there is no restriction stating that `Si != Sj`, so this makes the definitions a little imprecise in my mind.

The second is your assertion "Note that variable ‘u’ is not live in block 2 as ‘u’ is assigned a new value in block 1 before it is used in block 3."

The way I would look at this would be this:

1. Upon *entry* into block 2, before the statement `v = r + u` is
   executed (imagine a no-op empty statement inserted as the entry to
   each block, and another as the exit from the block), then both `r`
   and `u` *must* be live, because there exists an upcoming statement
   that uses both, and there is a path in the code from the entry to
   that statement that contains no intermediate assignments to either.
   Rather than imagining these extra empty statements, using the
   original semantics of the definitions, then we're just talking about
   the case where `Si == Sj`, because both refer to the `v = r + u`
   statement - there is trivially a path from a statement to itself
   containing no additional assignments in that sense. I find it easier
   to think about it with the extra empty entry and exit statements,
   though.
2. After the execution of `v = r + u`, however, at the imaginary
   block exit empty statement, it is now safe to consider `u` as not
   live (alternatively, dead), because nothing in block 4 uses it, and
   it's reassigned in block 1 before it's ever used again in either
   block 2 or 3.

So, part of the confusion seems to be thinking of whether a variable is live *in a particular block*, which doesn't really fit with the definitions - you need to think about whether a variable is live *at the point of a particular statement*. You could make the case that the variable `u` is both alive and dead in block 2, depending on whether you look at it before execution of the lone statement, or after...